# Generifying with static factory methods and constants in Java

Tags: java, android, generics

In my Android app, I have some very similar classes, let's call them `FooA` and `FooB`.

For each of these classes, I have a schema class that contains constants for the columns of the table - `FooASchema` and `FooBSchema`:

```
public final class FooASchema {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "foo_a_table";
    public static final String COL_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
    public static final String COL_PROPERTY_A = "property_a";
    public static final String COL_PROPERTY_B = "property_b";
    // COL_PROPERTY_C = ...

}


public final class FooBSchema {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "foo_b_table";
    public static final String COL_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
    public static final String COL_OTHER_PROPERTY_A = "other_property_a";
    // COL_OTHER_PROPERTY_B = ...

}
```

Both `FooA` and `FooB` have a static factory method that enables me to create them using a `Cursor`:

```
public static FooA from(Cursor cursor) {
    int categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FooASchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID));
    String propertyA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FooASchema.COL_PROPERTY_A));
    String propertyB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FooASchema.COL_PROPERTY_B));
    // int propertyC = ...

    return FooA(id, propertyA, propertyB, ...);
}


public static FooB from(Cursor cursor) {
    int categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FooBSchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID));
    int otherA = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FooASchema.COL_OTHER_PROPERTY_A));
    // String otherB = ...

    return FooB(id, otherA, otherB, ...);
}
```

Finally, I have two util classes that I use to retrieve data from the tables:

```
public final class FooAUtils {

    public static ArrayList<FooA> getFooAs(Context context, int categoryId) {
        ArrayList<FooA> fooAs = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = MyDbHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase.query(
                FooASchema.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                FooASchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(categoryId)},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            fooAs.add(FooA.from(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return fooAs;
    }

    // ...
}


public final class FooBUtils {

    public static ArrayList<FooA> getFooBs(Context context, int categoryId) {
        ArrayList<FooB> fooBs = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = MyDbHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase.query(
                FooBSchema.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                FooBSchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(categoryId)},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            fooBs.add(FooB.from(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return fooBs;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can see that most of the code between `FooA`-related classes and `FooB`-related classes are very similar, and especially in the util classes - where the code is almost identical.

I want to try to reduce this duplication, and I have been trying to do so using generics (I've read about them, but I haven't yet used them in a project).

For example, I want to be able to have a generic util class. Here's how I thought I could implement it:

```
public final class FooUtils {

    public static <T> get(Context context, int categoryId) {
        ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = MyDbHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase.query(
                BaseSchema.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                BaseSchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(categoryId)},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            items.add(T.from(cursor)); // ??
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    // ...

}
```

Where:

```
public interface BaseSchema {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME; // can't make this abstract?

    public static final String COL_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";

}

public final class FooASchema implements BaseSchema { ... }


public final class FooBSchema implements BaseSchema { ... }
```

But as you can see, I can't do `T.from(cursor)`, and I can't have an abstract constant `TABLE_NAME` that the subclasses can implement.

How can I call my static factory method in this way?

Is there a better way of approaching this and reducing code duplication?

Comment: Consider using a framework or library for this. What you want to do is not possible as such. Generics only work with instances; not with types. Maybe just consider this approach with factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your actual code you don't use an instance of the class to invoke the `form()` factory, you use a static method of the class :

```
fooAs.add(FooA.from(cursor));
```

With generics, you cannot use the parameterized type to invoke a method on it like that `items.add(T.from(cursor));` since the generic was erased after the compilation.

In your case, I see two ways of handling the problem :

- introducing a abstract base class with the common method and an abstract method that subclasses have to implement to create a`Foo` instance (`FooA`, `FooB`).
- keeping your way of doing and introducing an interface to create a `Foo` instance.
  You would have two implementation of it. One for `FooA` and another one for `FooB` and you could provide a instance of it in the `FooUtils.get()` method.

With the first option you could do the following.

**Base class**

```
public abstract class AbstractFooProcessing<T extends Foo> {

    public abstract T createFooInstance(Cursor cursor);

    public ArrayList<T> get(Context context, int categoryId) {
        ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = MyDbHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase.query(
                BaseSchema.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                BaseSchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(categoryId)},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            items.add(createFooInstance(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    // ...

}
```

**FooAProcessing**

```
public class FooAProcessing extends AbstractFooProcessing<FooA>{

    @Override
    public FooA createFooInstance(Cursor cursor) {
        return FooA.from(cursor);
    }

}
```

**FooBProcessing**

```
public class FooBProcessing extends AbstractFooProcessing<FooB>{

    @Override
    public FooB createFooInstance(Cursor cursor) {
        return FooB.from(cursor);
    }

}
```

---

With the second option you could do the following.

**FooProcessing interface**

```
public interface FooProcessing<T extends Foo> {    
    T createFooInstance(Cursor cursor);            
}
```

**FooProcessingA**

```
public class FooAProcessing implements FooProcessing<FooA>{

    @Override
    public FooA createFooInstance(Cursor cursor) {
        return FooA.from(cursor);
    }   
}
```

**FooProcessingB**

```
public class FooBProcessing implements FooProcessing<FooB>{

    @Override
    public FooB createFooInstance(Cursor cursor) {
        return FooB.from(cursor);
    }
}
```

**FooUtils** updated so that `get()` takes as argument a `FooProcessing` factory instance.

```
public final class FooUtils {

    public static <T extends Foo> ArrayList<T> get(Context context, int categoryId, FooProcessing<T> fooProcessing) {
        ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = MyDbHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase.query(
                BaseSchema.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                BaseSchema.COL_CATEGORY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(categoryId)},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            items.add(fooProcessing.createFooInstance(cursor)); // ??
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    // ...
    return items;

}
```

You can now call the FooUtils.get() method in this way :

```
...
FooProcessing fooAProcessing =  new FooAProcessing();
...
ArrayList<FooA> fooAs = FooAUtils.getFoo(context, category, fooAProcessing);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also provide an example for the second option so I have a better understanding of what you are suggesting?

Comment: You are welcome. Of course, it changes not a lot. I updated with the second option code.

Comment: Thank again @davidxxx . The other question I had was regarding `BaseSchema.TABLE_NAME` (at the moment, this doesn't actualy work). Considering that each Foo class (i.e. `FooA` and `FooB`) has a related schema class, and every schema class has the same category id constant, and a table name (different across schema classes) is there a way I can generalise getting the constants for the table name and category id columns. I hope that makes sense ;)

Comment: Actually, don't worry about it :) - I managed to sort it out by including `getTableName()` and `getCategoryIdColumn()` in `FooProcessing` interface (I opted for the second option).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In fact It is the solution i would propose to you.